# Import-PSSession - throwing credentials-mask

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I got a problem with a powershell-script used in our domain to create new users:
Helpdesk will call a .bat as administrator, this bat calls a script-file to automate the creation. In this script, two sessions are created and imported, to use the Exchange- and AD-cmdlets locally. 
During/after the import a second/third credential-mask gets thrown, but clicking "cancel" will do nothin, the script will run through without any issues. Nevertheless this annoys the helpdesk..
When running the .ps1 directly from the ISE, the mask won't be shown. Also, when C&Ping the Create-/Import part of the script to a new file and calling it the same way as before also won't show these mask..

Here a part of the .ps1-file:

```
<#
.DESCRIPTION
    Creates a new standard user
.NOTES
    Requires        : Exchange 2016 Remote Session
    Req.OS Version  : not tested
    Req.PS Version  : not tested
.EXAMPLE
    Create-User.ps1 -datapath \\path\to\userdata.csv -credentialobject $cred
 #>
Param (
    [string]$datapath, <#Folder where the CSVs sit #>
    [System.Management.Automation.CredentialAttribute()]$credentialobject = $null
)
#region SET global var definitions
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
Start-Transcript -path $ScriptLogPath  # | out-null

#endregion

#region SET var definitions

$userfile = "$datapath\userdata.txt"
$groupfile = "$datapath\groupdata.txt"

#Exchange
$MSXremotingserver = "exchangehostname"
$MSXdatabasenames = @("msx_db")

#AD
$domaincontroller = "dchostname"
$ADremotingserver = $domaincontroller
$BaseDN = "OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=local"

#endregion

#region Import Userdata
# CSV's are getting imported here - WORKING
#endregion

#region INIT Remotesession

#Get AD Creds / use given AD Creds
if (($credentialobject -ne $null) -and (($credentialobject.GetType()).name -eq "PSCredential")){
    $UserCredential = $credentialobject
}else{
    $UserCredential = Get-Credential
        # Get credentials to create the remote-sessions. Seems to be working.
}

$MSXSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionURI http://$MSXremotingserver/powershell -Credential $UserCredential
echo "import..."
$null = Import-PSSession $MSXSession -AllowClobber -DisableNameChecking  # | out-null
# After the import (Progress bars running through on top of the PS) another credential-mask appearing, "Cancel" makes the script run through without further errors.
echo "OK"

$ADSession = New-PSsession -Computername $ADremotingserver -Credential $UserCredential
Invoke-Command -Command {Import-Module ActiveDirectory -DisableNameChecking} -Session $ADSession  # | out-null
echo "import..."
Import-PSSession -Session $ADSession -Module "ActiveDirectory" -Prefix Remote -AllowClobber -DisableNameChecking  # | out-null
# After the import (Progress bars running through on top of the PS) another credential-mask appearing, "Cancel" makes the script run through without further errors.
echo "OK"


#AD-user already existing?
if ([bool](get-remoteaduser -LDAPFilter "(SamAccountName=$($userdata.Kuerzel))")){
    #Throw custom error - AD-User bereits vorhanden! 
}


#build Account...

# AD-user and Mailbox are created and configured. WORKING!


#endregion 

#region END Script

Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
Stop-Transcript
Write-Host "Beende Skript..."
start-sleep -Seconds 3
exit 10000

#endregion
```

And here's how the .ps1 is being called:

```
%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file \\helpdeskserver\powershell_userdata$\Create-User.ps1 \\helpdeskserver\path\to\csv"
```

I don't know what to do. Tried many different versions of each command, tried piping the in/output, nothing will do..
Google doesn't seem to know that behaviour, neither anyone here on Stackoverflow..

Thanks for any tips and help, I'll apprechiate!

Regards, Ting3l

Edit: When starting the .bat-file without administrative rights (Or with right-click -> other user.. -> admin-account) the second/third credential-dialog won't appear, instead I get an "Index out of range"-exception.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's unimportant, but you can try to exit the session by `Exit-PSSession`. After that use `exit 1000`. Becoaser when you use `exit` in the session it completes the session (wherein all code after will be ignored, but script will have successful completed)